# Create an empty delta lake table in databricks with schema available

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I have the schema defined. How can i crate an empty delta lake table in databricks azure. I see this command with no schema defined but I get error as though I have the all necessary permission.I just created the schema. Can someone get me the command if lets say I have schema defined in a ***schema*** variable like this:

> schema = "authenticationMechanism STRING,authenticationMechanismId
> STRING"

Error for below code:

```
Operation failed: "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.", 403,

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
main.deltalake_db.test_delta
```

Comment: What are you using to execute this command?

Comment: %sql .. if thats what you meant?

Comment: just to be clear the error message you see is for "Create Table...." command

Comment: If you are creating empty delta lake table in SQL notebook it won't give authentication error which you have provided. Could you please give brief explanation about what you have done before creating table?

Comment: I enabled the Unity Catalog, created a metastore, ran command to create a schema and now I am trying to create a table insdie the scema created

Comment: ran this command before that" %sql
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS
main.deltalake_db"